# Retrieve more than 1000 contacts using EWS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am having an outlook account which has nearly 2500 contacts. I am trying to fetch those contacts using EWS managed API for java. But it only returns me 1000 contacts. I did some research and found that it can be done by setting the offset value, I tried the same but haven't been successful. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks :)

Below is the piece of code I am using.

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(numItems);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, new Mailbox("a@b.com")),view);    
ArrayList<Item> contact = findResults.getItems();
```

Comment: Where is the part where you set the Offset?

Comment: It is set for the view. Below is the link which shows the example, but as it is for dot net, it could not help much. http://gsexdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/dealing-with-throttling-restrictions-in.html

Comment: So, with the Offset it will return again 1000 starting at Offset, but not more than 1000, right? Can you copy Items from one ItemView to another? - I don't know EWS, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, silly me. I think you have to call the first two lines with increasing Offset and adding results to the `ArrayList` each time until you have all your contacts. If you make a new ArrayList, the previous results are lost.

Comment: Yes, it cannot be done that way. Actually, I am not able to understand where to put offset and how to implement the whole solution for java. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. The offset is there so you can page through the results. This is off the cuff, so it may not be entirely correct, but it should get the point across.

```
int offset = 0;
int pageSize = 100;
ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize, offset, OffsetBasepoint.Beginning);
FindItemsResults<Item> find;
boolean more = true;
List<Item> contacts = new ArrayList<Item>();
while (more) {
    find = service.findItems(...);
    contacts.addAll(find.getItems());
    if (find.isMoreAvailable()){
        offset += pageSize;
        view.setOffset(offset);
    } else {
        more = false;
    }
 }
```

Use isMoreAvailable() to determine if you have more items on the server, and if so, increment the offset by the number of items you're fetching in each call and set it in the ItemView. Then you can retrieve the next batch until you've retrieved all of the results.

Comment: Worked for me too.I did not even noticed that only 1000 items are returned until i wrote an integration test to check for the performance.
For me a page size of 50 was the fastest.
But that may be dependend of the running exchange server. My is running in a virtual box.